# TFS 2012 express edition fails installation - Due to pre req SQL server

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-2008-r2

I am installing TFS 2012 Express edition and I fail at the wizard that runs "Readiness check". It fails at the Data tier section.. with error

> TF400533: In order for this wizard to upgrade to the latest version of SQL Server Express, you will first need to install Service Pack 2 or newer, and then re-run this wizard.  It is recommended that you run Microsoft Updates  which will install the current service pack automatically (You may need to enable Microsoft  Updates from the Windows control panel).

Question:
What service pack 2 is this talking about. If its SQL 2008 R2, then I installed it and I get the same error. If its TFS 2012 or SQL 2012 , there is no SP2.

I did install SQL server 2012 express edition separately and and then re run the TFS 2012 express edition install, it still fails at the same point.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the version of SQL Express that is packaged with TFS is not capable of upgrading the older version of SQL express you have.  It must be pulled forward for the upgrade to work.  So, we detect you're behind the minimum version it's capable of upgrading and show that message.

This article discussed a few options.  If windows update works for you (optional updates) that is the easiest path.

http://elhajj.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/on-dealing-with-tfs-error-tf400533/

If you run that SP2 installer directly (next, next, next), it can just install SP2 but not against the SQLExpress instance on your box (sigh).  It's not obvious - if the above link doesn't get you going, let me know and I'll include more detailed steps.

Comment: Installing SQL Server SP3 via Windows Update worked for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

How about [SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30437)?

Comment: I have SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2.. and still I am getting the same error. I then installed SQL Server 2012 Express, but the problem persists. Now going to install SQL Server 2012 SP2

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2012 Express will install SQL Server 2012 Express while TFS configuration is running, so my advice to you, you will need to uninstall any any instance of existing SQL server you have and re-run TFS configuration wizard, remember to backup any database you have before uninstall.

[Uninstall an Existing Instance of SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412.aspx)

[Uninstall an Existing Instance of SQL Server 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)